# Как изменить порядок вывода меток поста?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

При оформлении поста на wordpress добавляю метки, допустим - г, к, а. Нажимаю публиковать пост и метки располагаются - а, г, к. (в алфавитном порядке, стандартно для wordpress).

Можно как-то это поменять, чтобы сортировка не происходила и метки поста выстраивались в том порядке, в котором были добавлены.

Дело в том, что название поста на сайте формируется из 2 тегов, получается первых 2 тегов по алфавиту. А так иногда в название не попадают ключевые метки.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет какого-то "порядка добавления" - это просто визуальный эффект на стороне клиента. А по сути дело обстоит как с рубриками: у Вас есть список чек-боксов, Вы выбираете нужные. Но от того, какой чек-бокс Вы кликните раньше, порядок вывода не изменится.

Comment: Вопрос решен, все можно сделать.

Comment: так дайте ответ на свой вопрос, если решён - интересно посмотреть, как именно удалось это реализовать (если действительно удалось и не каким-то "костыльным" способом)